# Скачивание измененного файла XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Если делать сохранение в том же php файле, то я делаю вот так

```
$xmlFileName = 'test2.xml';
$xmlData = $xml->asXML();
$xmlLength = strlen($xmlData);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$xmlFileName);
header('Content-Length: '.$xmlLength);
echo $xmlData
```

Но в этом файле у меня также есть вывод этого же документа, тогда так сохранение не получится. Как можно будет передать переменную $xmlData с xml документом в другой файл?

Правильный будет вариант, сохранить файл на сервере, потом отправить ссылку с GET с названием файлом, там этот файл прогрузить, отправить на сохранение на компьютер, а потом удалить на сервере?

Answer (score 1):

Скрипты в PHP могут возвращать значения. Вы можете сделать `return $xmlData` вместо `echo $xmlData`.
 В том месте где вам нужно вывести результат работы скрипта сделайте `echo require '/path/to/script/script.php'`, а там, где нужно что-то сделать вместо вывода просто `$xml = require '/path/to/script/script.php'`

Comment: Это просто адовая практика.

Comment: Если человек работает в процедурном стиле, у него нет объектной архитектуры и все завязано на отдельных скриптах. Такая практика встречается, и довольно часто.
Конечно, можно сказать, чтобы он переписывал все, но есть ли в этом смысл ? Возможно, ему этот скрипт нужен для личного одноразового пользования. Так что считаю ваш минус необоснованным.
Если вы посмотрите, то многие фреймворки работают именно так. В одном скрипте настраивается и формируется объект. В другом скрипте он таким образом подключается.